# Medievalesque fantasy stories on audio cassette in Early 1990s

Tags: story-identification, medieval, audio-book

As a small child in the early 1990s I eagerly listened to a series of short stories on audio cassette that took placing in a strongly medieval world, involving a jester (who perhaps ultimately gets crushed by an anvil or a piece of falling masonry), there may also be a bear. I realize this is almost nothing to go on, so sorry for the lack of clarity!

Comment: Can you say something about the cover illuatrations on the cassettes? Did the jester appear in all the stories, or just one? Roughly how many tapes in total? Any information helps...